# split a line and print in second line

Tags: python, unix, awk

I have input file like this

```
 @HWI-ST1072:185:C325WACXX:1:1101:8553:1994:1:N:#CAGATT
 NGGGGCGATAGAGTAAGATTTTATTTTAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATTTAAAA
 +
 #0<FFBBFFFFFFFBFBFFIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIFFFFFB#########
 @HWI-ST1072:185:C325WACXX:1:1101:16084:1999:1:N:#CCAATT
 NGGAGTGGAGTGGTTGTGGTGGTTTGGGTTGTTGATTGTGTATTTGGAATA
 +
 #0<FFFFFFFFFFIFFFIIIIIIFFFFFFFBBFBFFIBFFIFIIIFBFFII
 @HWI-ST1072:185:C325WACXX:1:1101:16829:1993:1:N:#TGATGT
 NGGGTAGTAGTTTGGTGTATGTATTATTGTATATGGCGGTGAGAGTTAGGG
```

and i want to print the second line with sequence in first line

output

```
 @HWI-ST1072:185:C325WACXX:1:1101:8553:1994:1:N:#CAGATT
 CAGATT
 +
 #0<FFBBFFFFFFFBFBFFIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIFFFFFB#########
 @HWI-ST1072:185:C325WACXX:1:1101:16084:1999:1:N:#CCAATT
 CCAATT
 +
 #0<FFFFFFFFFFIFFFIIIIIIFFFFFFFBBFBFFIBFFIFIIIFBFFII
 @HWI-ST1072:185:C325WACXX:1:1101:16829:1993:1:N:#TGATGT
 TGATGT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('path/to/input') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if line.startswith("@"):
            line = line.strip()
            print(line)
            print(line.rsplit("#", 1)[1])
        elif any(line.startswith(e) for e in "#+"):
            print(line.strip())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'#' 'seq{$0=seq;seq=""} /@/{seq=$NF} 1' file
```

Comment: @abh You're welcome. I'm curious though - why select the 8-line over the 1-line answer???

Comment: i was doing in same way till splitting the files but i was confused how to add next lines(i got a hint from him) and he replied first so @Ed Morton

Comment: how can i learn advanced awk so that i can solve this kind of problems,can you suggest me some links etc... @Ed Morton

Comment: Get the book "Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition" by Arnold Robbons and start lurking at the comp.lang.awk newsgroup. There's really nothing advanced about that problem/solution though, it's pretty basic stuff - just find a pattern on one line, save part of that line and print it on the next line.